# SQL inserts and updates in same query very slow

Tags: sql, insert, sql-update

At first, my software would do each inserts and each updates in different querys. It would determine wether to insert or update with this piece of code :

```
If (CInt(database.ExecuteScalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & TableNames.LOG & " WHERE " & Columns.DATE_ & "='" & day & "'")) > 0) Then
    database.Update(TableNames.LOG, row, Columns.DATE_ & "='" & day & "'")
Else
    database.Insert(TableNames.LOG, row)
End If
```

But this was pretty slow (like 12 seconds for 80 rows). So I want to speed it up by putting everything in one query. After a couple of fast tweaks in the code, I managed to send a query that would look like this :

```
INSERT INTO *tablename* [...];
UPDATE *tablename* SET [...] WHERE [...];
INSERT INTO *tablename* [...];
INSERT INTO *tablename* [...];
UPDATE *tablename* SET [...] WHERE [...];
```

And so on...

But it's barely faster. I know I'm doing something wrong because 10 seconds for 80 rows is ridiculously slow. What am I missing here?

Note that each insert and updates are on different rows.

Comment: What's your table definition?  What are your indexed columns?  If the values being inserted are quite large and/or the indexes are poorly designed, then the updates could be quite slow.

Comment: It's a pretty small table with one column with a date, another with a filepath (varchar(127)) and another one with a file name (varchar(31))

Comment: What language are you using? You should try to prepare 1 insert statement and 1 update statement, and then execute them repeatedly... that is certainly more efficient than building a script with multiple insert/update statements. Then you should think about wrapping all up in a single transaction. Autocommit statement execution is a show-stopper if you have a lot of data to write.

Comment: How are you measuring the total time?  Is there overhead on your application side which is padding out the time to actually execute the commands?  How long does it take to run these commands directly in your RDMS tool?

Comment: @Fazz : I'm using VB.NET. I'm not sure what you mean. How can I insert multiple rows with one insert and update multiple rows with one update?

Comment: @Jon of All Trades : I measure the total time programatically in the code. I don't have an RDMS tool. It takes about 100 ms to execute a single insert/update statement.

Comment: It's entirely possible that your measuring things beyond the actual query time.  There are many free tools for RDMS management, such as SQL Studio and phpMyAdmin.  You can insert multiple rows using `INSERT INTO Tbl (Fld) VALUES (1), (2)`, on MS SQL.

Comment: Thanks but I'm quite sure I'm measuring the time it takes correctly. This is not the issue here.